# How to compute electric field between constantly changing potentials (LFP data)

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, potential

I have a set of LFP(local field potential) data, which is basically the voltage of different points in the brain at different times. I would like to calculate the electric field at these points at all times. So imagine there are multiple points in space, with constantly changing voltages, and we want to find the electric field profile in this space, across time.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field $\vec E$ is (in a static situation) the negative gradient of the electric potential $\phi$. If you have discrete potential measurement data of points which are closely together, you can simply numerically compute the gradient to get the electric field.

For example, let's say you want to know the field at the point $(x,y,z)$, where the potential is $\phi_0$ and you also know the potential at the points $(x+dx,y,z)$,$(x,y + dy,z)$ and $(x,y,z + dz)$, where it is $\phi_x$,$\phi_y$ and $\phi_z$, respectively. Then it holds
$$
\vec E(x,y,z) \approx \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\phi_x - \phi_0}{dx} \\ \frac{\phi_y - \phi_0}{dy} \\ \frac{\phi_z - \phi_0}{dz} \end{pmatrix}~.
$$
The result is just an approximation, because there is data missing for the space between the points, which becomes better and better the closer the points are together.